# How to find specific span from th class using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

I want to pick only one html `<span>` element from a `<th>` class and print on terminal. I've tried using [1] at the end of the `<span>` but it didn't work out.

I've tried this with selenium:

```
for element in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div/table/thead/tr/th/span[1]'):
    print(element.text)
```

The html is the following:

```html
<thead><tr class="C($tertiaryColor) Fz(xs) Ta(end)"><th class="Ta(start) W(100px) Fw(400) Py(6px)"><span>Date</span></th><th class="Fw(400) Py(6px)"><span>Open</span></th><th class="Fw(400) Py(6px)"><span>High</span></th><th class="Fw(400) Py(6px)"><span>Low</span></th><th class="Fw(400) Py(6px)"><span>Close*</span></th><th class="Fw(400) Py(6px)"><span>Adj Close**</span></th><th class="Fw(400) Py(6px)"><span>Volume</span></th></tr></thead>
```

Needing more information, leave a comment.

Comment: when you print out driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div/table/thead/tr/th/span[1]') do you get any results? could you give us the site where the span is located? to better assist?

Comment: Your question is missing basic debugging details. We need to see a link to that page or entire XML of it in order to help here

Comment: This is the page: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BTC-EUR/history

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *SPAN* s are decendents of the *TH* s. Similarly the *TH* s are decendents of the *TR*. So you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- *xpath*:

  ```
  for element in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//thead/tr//th/span'):
          print(element.text)
  ```
- *css-selectors*:

  ```
  for element in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, 'thead > tr th > span'):
          print(element.text)
  ```

---

### Update

To identify the first `<span>` you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- *xpath*:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "thead > tr th:nth-child(1) > span").text)
  ```
- *css-selectors*:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//thead/tr//following::th[1]/span").text)
  ```

Comment: There are some 6 spans at the th class, I need to pick only one span, and cannot be by text. I will parse numbers in another "th class" and these numbers changes everyday.

Comment: Which specific `<span>` are you looking for?

Comment: The first `<span>`

Comment: @Rodrigo Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: I received this error: `for element in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//thead/tr//following::th[1]/span").text:`
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'

Then, I changed to `for element in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//thead/tr//following::th[1]/span"):
    print(element.text)` and still prints all spans and now without a "Date" span: Open
High
Low
Close*
Adj Close**
Volume

Comment: @Rodrigo Neither you need a _list_ nor you need _`find_elements`_. You need the first `<span>` and you need _`find_element()`_