# How to get list of inputs using find element in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to enter OTP in the browser for each of 5 INPUTs. If I type in the codes myself, it jumps to the next INPUT. In Selenium, it stays on one input and tries to enter code in the first INPUT box.

```
input = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//form//input[@type='text']").send_keys("123456")
```

I want to get all inputs in the list and then enter OTP on each box by the loop.

Comment: Quick comment: Try to avoid using _Python built-ins_ (e.g `input`) as your variables names.

Answer (score 1):

Get the elements and then iterate over them:

```
import time

for element in browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//form//input[@type='text']"):
    element.send_keys("some_string\n")
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: I would suggest that you put the `browser.find_*` statement inside the loop itself in case the page changes after each entry. Also, you might want to add a 500ms wait after each `.send_keys()` to give the page a chance to process the change since from OP's description, manual entry moves the cursor. It will give the page a chance to run whatever JS it has when INPUT values are changed.

Answer (score 0):

To get all inputs in the list and then enter OTP on each box by the loop you need to use [`find_elements()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71025446/7429447) to make a *list* of the `<input>` elements as follows:

```
input_elements = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//form//input[@type='text']")
for input_element in input_elements:
    input_element.send_keys("123456")
```