# Cannot get out of iframe

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, iframe

I have written a code to click on a textarea inside a form. To clear content of the text area and write a new text I have to go into that `iframe`. I am able to clear content and write a new text but unable to click on submit or cancel button which is not inside that `iframe` (apparently outside of `iframe`)

I have tried using `driver.switch_to.parent_frame()` and `driver.switch_to.default_content()` but using these two commands my `webdriver` restart and closes. I have also tried using

```
currentWindow = driver.current_window_handle;
driver.switch_to.window(currentWindow)
```

Here is my code

```
currentWindow = driver.current_window_handle;
KeyMessage_Input = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='id_Message']").click()
time.sleep(3)
iframe = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"wysihtml5-sandbox")
# Switch to the iframe context
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
textbox = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,"body")
textbox.click()
# Clear the textbox contents
textbox.clear()
#time.sleep(2)
textbox.send_keys("This is Key Message")
time.sleep(3)

driver.switch_to.window(currentWindow)
```

Here is html code:

```
<textarea id="textarea_1677326708786" class="editable-wysihtml5" style="display: none;"></textarea>
<iframe class="wysihtml5-sandbox" security="restricted" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" width="0" height="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" style="display: inline-block; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-collapse: separate; border-color: rgb(118, 118, 118); border-style: solid; border-width: 0.8px; clear: none; float: none; margin: 0px; outline: rgb(0, 0, 0) none 0px; outline-offset: 0px; padding: 2px; position: static; inset: auto; z-index: auto; vertical-align: baseline; text-align: start; box-sizing: border-box; box-shadow: none; border-radius: 0px; width: 566px; height: 250px;"></iframe>
```

for submit and cancel button

```
<div class="editable-buttons"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm editable-submit"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></button><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm editable-cancel"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you are within an [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) to interact with any of the [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70203974/7429447) which is out of that frame you have to shift back [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447)'s [*focus*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59521886/7429447) using either of the following [`switch_to`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.switch_to) commands:

- Using *`parent_frame()`*:

  ```
  driver.switch_to.parent_frame()
  ```
- Using *`default_content()`*:

  ```
  driver.switch_to.default_content()
  ```