# How to identify and click on the text if it's available in multiple locations on the website using Python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have the keyword "Know More" (using the keyword I find Xpath of that and performing actions like click) and the website has similar words like "Know More" for students loan, educational loan...etc which are not buttons but they are anchor tags. Now I want to click the "Know More" keyword using XPATH which is for "student loan" but student loan is available in  block.

```
<div class="content">
    <h5 class="mb-10">For Students</h5>
    <h3>Enabling a hassle-free learning journey with curated solutions</h3>
    <h4>#CampusPower #StudentLoan</h4>
    <ul class="bullet-list bullet-list-orange mb-20">
        <li>One stop solution for all your education needs</li>
        <li>Customised product bundles for the country of your choice</li>
        <li>Explore pre & post admission guidance</li>
        <li>Learn how to manage your money.</li>
        </ul>
    <a id="ga-ese-whatsnew-1" href="/campus-power/student" class="ic-btn ic-btn-gradient">Know More</a>
    </div>
```

I don't want to take manual Xpath so I used code based on Keyword Xpath lik this.

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f"//*[contains(text(), '{keyword}')]"))
        )
element.click()
```

It is clicking only the first "Know More" on the webpage which is for another loan. How to click on "Know More" for student loan any help on suggestion is appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: you should first locate the 'student loan' section and then find the 'know more' under it instead of finding it directly on the driver webelement

Comment: How to do it can you elaborate it @AjeetVerma.

Comment: if `<a id="ga-ese-whatsnew-1" href="/campus-power/student" class="ic-btn ic-btn-gradient">Know More</a>
` is your target 'Know more' which you want to click then you should directly find this with the given `id` (By.ID)

Comment: WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'ga-ese-whatsnew-1'))).click()

Comment: What if I shouldn't take 'id' manually in that case what should be the approach? only using keyword.

Comment: I didn't get, what do you mean by taking id manually?

Comment: I have given instructions to find the Xpath of a keyword on a webpage to perform the click option. So I can't go to the "inspect element" and take the 'id' name manually and perform the click action.

Answer (score 0):

To click on **Know More** link within the **For Students** section, you can locate the element with text ***For Students*** first and then with reference to that [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70203974/7429447) you can traverse the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) to locate the required link inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) using either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *XPATH* and *`following-sibling`*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//h5[text()='For Students']//following-sibling::a[1]"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and *`following`*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//h5[text()='For Students']//following::a[1]"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and *`following-sibling`* and the text *Know More*:

  ```
  keyword = "Know More"
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//h5[text()='For Students']//following-sibling::a[text()='{keyword}']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and *`following`* and the text *Know More*:

  ```
  keyword = "Know More"
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//h5[text()='For Students']//following::a[text()='{keyword}']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Update

As an alternative you can also use the following [*locator strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over):

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[text()='One stop solution for all your education needs']//following::a[text()='Know More']"))).click()
```

Comment: I shouldn't go through "inspect elements" and find the code. As per the given instructions I need to pass the "Know More" keyword and find the Xpath and perform click action but it should be for student only.

Comment: @jainmiahShaik I'll update my answer by that time check if the first 2 locators works for you as well.

Comment: @jainmiahShaik Check out the updated code in the third and forth option and let me know the status.

Comment: I used //*[text()='One stop solution for all your education needs']//following::a[text()='Know More'][1] but its giving error

Comment: @jainmiahShaik Checkout the answer update wrt the text _One stop solution for all your education needs_

Comment: WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[text()='One stop solution for all your education needs']//following::*[text()='Know More']"))).click() , to make this code generic I used above code but its giving me error SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document':

Comment: @jainmiahShaik Now you are making a simple usecae complicated :) Feel free to raise a new question with your new requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this XPath:

```
//h5[text()='For Students']//following::a[text()='Know More'][1]
```

Comment: instead of '//h5' can I give [text()='For Students']//following::a[text()='Know More'][1]

Comment: No, relative XPath always must start with `//`. If you do not want to give `h5`, then you can give `*` instead. Something like this `//*[text()='For Students']//following::a[text()='Know More'][1]`

Comment: @Shawn I believe you still won't need that index i.e. `[1]`

Comment: I used //*[text()='One stop solution for all your education needs']//following::a[text()='Know More'][1] but its giving error.

Comment: @jainmiahShaik -What error does it give? if you inspect the DOM and copy-paste this XPath expression, does it locate 1 element? or zero elements?

Comment: @undetectedSelenium - Hmm you may be right, however I was just ensuring that it locates the first occurrence of `Know More` node. Because there may be chances that there are more than one 'Know More' nodes and `following` will just locate/select all the nodes after the current node isn't it!

Comment: can't we make it generic like this WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[text()='One stop solution for all your education needs']//following::*[text()='Know More']"))).click()