# How can I print the entire content of a list object?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriver

when I execute

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)  # Adjust the timeout value as needed
parent_div = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".el-table-box")))
print(parent_div)
```

I get

```
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="136cf2ec383dc1418886e107a4041971", element="5033E27DBF4D61FD1E1C653BCA654DF5_element_8")>]
```

Is parent_div a list object? How can I print its entire content?

Answer (score 0):

### [**visibility_of_all_elements_located()**](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.visibility_of_all_elements_located)

[*`visibility_of_all_elements_located()`*](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.html#visibility_of_all_elements_located) is the expectation for checking that all elements are present on the DOM of a page and visible. A locator is used to find the elements which returns the list of WebElements once they are located and visible.

Accordingly *`parent_div`* contains a list of [WebElements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70203974/7429447) which prints:

```
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="136cf2ec383dc1418886e107a4041971", element="5033E27DBF4D61FD1E1C653BCA654DF5_element_8")>]
```

---

### This usecase

To print the value of any of the attributes you need to use the [`get_attribute(attributename)`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method and using [*list comprehension*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72573441/7429447) you can use the following solution:

```
print([my_elem.get_attribute("attributename") for my_elem in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".el-table-box")])
```

- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  ```